# How I initialize a git Repository and add hooks and files into it?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pre-commit-hook

I want to initialize an empty local repository and then fill it with the data (files) from [this](https://github.com/dvdvideo1234/Test) one. I want to attach a pre-commit hook for getting me the last revision number and auto-insert it in the source as a text. I red that if I want to do that I need also some crazy folders with names starting with dots ( .git, .gitattrubutes e.g. ). So far I figured out that the structure should look like something like that on the master/*.* branch:

```
.gitattributes
.git/(hooks,logs,refs.. e.g.)
Diff.txt,
text.c,
.....
```

How should I prepare the pre-commit hook for doing that ( if the lastest revision is 120, it gets 120 increments it and writes 121 )

I am using windows 7 and Tortoise Git

Thanks !

Comment: Can you clarify what **you** mean with _revision number_ in this case, commit-sha, file-sha or a custom number (git uses sha for identifying revisions and can therefore not be sequential)?

Comment: It should be some custom number ( Like in SVN ), since I have to print it to identify the installed revision on the servers, though commit/file hash is very long for the terminal to print.

Comment: After I've put a matching string I got: 

Git Commit ID: $Id: 6715b1028ee270c0a435b04cdbbcf4d952f8130d $

Thought it does not seem to be related to a commit, but rather the hash of that file that it's in. Is there any way to call like ...
`
"Version : " + tostring ( getCommitCount( GitRepo ) + 1);
`
Or just get the firs 7 symbols of the head revision
`
"Version: " + substring(getCommitID(GitRepo),0,6);
`

Comment: Have a look at chapter "Keyword expansion" at http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes where they describe how you can add some customization to keyword expansion, maybe that can be of any help.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. May be that's why After setting the ID in test.c my content looks like that
`
Commit( K + 2 )

Git Commit ID: $Id: 6715b1028ee270c0a435b04cdbbcf4d952f8130d $
`

Which is actually the hash of the file itself ...

Comment: I managed to do this using a Lua pre-commit script, which does modify the last line of the test.c file with a given delimiter, after which it checks for revision number string, converts it to a number increments it and walla ;)

Answer (score 0):

It can be made using also Tortoise GIT/SVN with Lua custom pre-commit script

For EXAMPLE:

Right click the repository and then select "Git Sync ..."

```
Local  Branch: master
Remote Branch: master
Remote URL: origin
```

Click Pull and then Close. The local revision is updated

Right click on the local repository, go to Tortoise Git.

On the right-popping context menu Select Settings

On the settings tree ( right ) select Hooks scripts

Click "Add"

```
Hook type: Pre-Commit hook
Working tree path: ( Here lays the path to your local directory repo )
```

In "Command Line To Execute:" you have to put two paths. The first one is the 
path to "lua.exe" ( Let's say D:\IDES\Lua\lua.exe ), which will execute your script, the second is the script for execution. Let's say my repo looks like this:

```
D:\Repos\stm32f4-dac\..
    pre-commit.lia
    dsp-stm-32f4.h <-- On the last line we have the revision number
    dsp-stm-32f4.c
```

Then you should put there:

D:\IDES\Lua\lua.exe[only space here]D:\Repos\stm32f4-dac\pre-commit.lua

In "pre-commit.lua" Find the last line in the file, Match the revision number with Lua's string library, convert it to a number, increment it, generate a new string then write it to the file ( dsp-stm-32f4.h ).